# From a parameter-usage viewpoint, is calling a table-valued functions from ADO.NET the same as a stored procedure or the same as a parametrised query?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, user-defined-functions, sqlparameter

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/brownfield/how-data-access-code-affects-database-performance) warns of the performance pitfalls of using parametrised queries rather than stored procedures. The basic idea is that the server has to guess the data type of your parameters and its guesses pollute the cache. My confusion comes from the article only mentioning stored procedures as a solution. As far as I know, user-defined table-valued function are just as strongly typed as stored procedures, so the server shouldn't have to guess when using them. However, I also know that ADO.NET only has [a special `ComamndType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.commandtype?view=net-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) for stored procedures, so I don't know how it knows that it's talking to a user-defined table-valued function rather than passing around raw SQL.

My question is this: Given that I can't tell ADO.NET that what I'm telling it to call is a user-defined table-valued function rather than a stored procedure, am I at risk of it treating my call to a user-defined table-valued function as a parametrised query and therefore facing performance issues? Or is ADO.NET smart enough to know that user-defined table-valued functions have obvious parameters?

Comment: 1) don't ignore that this article is from 2009. 2) whenever you're worried about performance: _try it yourself_ - since performance is _very_ dependent on your specific usecase. and noone external could give any qualified answer about _your_ system.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Very true, but I imagine that how ADO.NET talks to table-valued functions will be well-known and independent of my system.

Comment: yes. but what _impact_ it has is _very_ dependent on your system. and your source information _could_ be very out of date and simply incorrect. so yeah; racing your horses is the best way to get reliable performance data. besides that, i guess we can only give opinions.

Comment: See following : https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/ado-net-using-stored-procedure/

Comment: @jdweng Why would an article that is *uniquely* about stored procedures have any relevance here?

Comment: @J.Mini : Read the title of this posting.  The OP is asking what is a difference between a stored procedure and a query.  My link shows how to call the stored procedure.

Comment: @jdweng Why would showing how to call something explain the difference between that and something else?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Did SQL Sever not have table-valued functions until after 2009? My best guesses indicate the author should have known about them https://web.archive.org/web/20081221213657/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: The query cache has improved a lot since 2009

Comment: @Flydog57 But the issues around incorrect parameter types have not changed

Comment: You will have an overhead of multiple query plans if you use `n/varchar` types in an ad-hoc batch, regardless if you are calling a TVF or not.

Comment: @Charlieface If you have evidence for that, then you've got a good answer to this question.

Comment: @J.Mini : The OP did not understand how to call a stored procedure and my link showed the correct way of calling the stored procedure.   It is obvious the OP already knew how to perform a SQL Query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, they are not the same.**

While both get their parameters coerced into the respective types, therefore no issues with sargeable queries, an ad-hoc batch against a TVF still gets a new query plan, so you have the overhead of a recompilation.

> As far as I know, user-defined table-valued function are just as strongly typed as stored procedures, so the server shouldn't have to guess when using them.

No they are different things. Procedures have query plans already compiled, TVFs only get their plans compiled when they are used, so if you are using a new data type (or something else changed in the query) then you get a recompile.

You can see this by examining the query plans generated [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9yVVsg6v). Note how the `query_hash` values are the same in the procedure case, but not in the TVF cases.

Comment: I can't stress just how surprising I've found this answer. It's the only case I can think of where it's better to write a stored procedure than write the equivalent user-defined table-valued function. I feel like there's a major and terrifying gap in my education.

Comment: They are two different things and hav different purposes. TVFs cannot contain multiple statements, or do anything other than a `SELECT`. It could be argued that TVFs are a better version of views, and perhaps you should create a procedure to select from the TVF, in other words use both at the same time.

Comment: You're right. I'm just expressing my surprise that this is the only time that I've ever seen an argument for writing a procedure instead of a table-valued function (in a situation where either could do the job).

Comment: *"TVFs cannot contain multiple statements"* - That's not entirely true. There are are two kinds of TVFs in SQL Server, *inline* and *multi-statement*. The former works the same as a view; the query in the function is inlined with the outer query by the optimizer. The latter works the same as a stored procedure, `INSERT`ing the results into a table variable; the results are fully realized prior to being processed by the outer query, so if the outer query's predicate could reduce those results, the optmizer has no way of doing it.

Comment: Sorry I took for granted we were talking iTVFs