# Is SQL Server able to reuse execution plans for functions when types differ in a meaningless way? Or is that only true of stored procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, user-defined-functions

Consider the following queries on a user-defined inline-table-valued function, `foo`, which has one parameter, `@bar varchar(MAX)`:

```sql
DECLARE @Long nvarchar(500)
SELECT * FROM foo(@long)
```

```sql
DECLARE @Short varchar(5)
SELECT * FROM foo(@Short)
```

Suppose that these are run in sequence and that they are the first time `foo` has ever been called. Is there any chance at all that SQL server will use the cached execution plan from the first call for the second? Or is it **absolutely guaranteed** that it won't?

I've [recently discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76245130/10319707) that if `foo` were a stored procedure (e.g. using `EXEC sp_foo @Short`), then SQL Server will coerce the argument to match `@bar`'s type and may therefore use the same execution plan for both queries. I'm asking this question because I've been put under the impression that the same is not true for table-valued functions.

Comment: How is this different from what I already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76245130/14868997 where I showed that the query plans are indeed different in TVFs https://dbfiddle.uk/9yVVsg6v Nothing is **guaranteed** when it comes to query plans, but as far as I understand it, there is no way these two queries will match the same cached plan

Comment: @Charlieface You've demonstrated that it **might** not use the same plan. I am asking if it's absolutely guaranteed that it won't.

Comment: Noone is going to be able to prove anything unless they have access to the compiler's source code. Having said that, it does seem it is able in some situations to use the same plan https://dbfiddle.uk/z0uE3XZc

Comment: The only absolute guarantee is death and taxes. What actual problem are you trying to solve? If you need the plan non-reuse, probably better to use option(recompile). In my opinion, ITFs should only be used for non-table queriing type of code (like string manipulation), where it shouldn't matter the QP

Comment: @siggemannen I'm trying to compare the execution of functions and procedures. I have no real problem yet. Only theoretical questions.

Comment: Because this is an inline table-valued function - there will never be a separate execution plan for that function.  The code from that function will be incorporated into the calling query and then an execution plan will be generated.  If the code using that function is the same - then it is likely to use the same execution plan.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely guaranteed that the plans won't be shared.  SQL Server matches queries to cached plans using a binary comparison.  SQL plans are even whitespace dependent, i.e. run a query twice, but with different whitespace and you will get two cached plans.  For parameterized queries, the parameter definitions have to match as well.

Comment: Do you have a source or an easy-to-run test to prove this?

Comment: https://bertwagner.com/posts/whitespace-letter-case-and-other-things-that-prevent-plan-reuse/  demonstrates this behavior.    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-create-plan-guide-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#plan-guide-matching-requirements discusses how plan guides must match exactly, character for character for @type='SQL' plan guides.

Comment: The proof is in the pudding, they get the same `query_hash` and `query_plan_hash` so this answer is not true https://dbfiddle.uk/z0uE3XZc

Comment: @Charlieface There are still two plans.  the plans may be identical, but they are not "shared" which is how I read the OP's question.

Comment: @StrayCatDBA Could be true. Can we prove that?

Comment: they have different plan_handle's......